# Prisma2 Error: Invalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation: Unknown arg `tags` in data.tags for type PostUncheckedCreateInput

Tags: graphql, nexus, prisma, prisma2, nexus-prisma

I want to create a post with a list of tags attached to it. The models are connected many-to-many (one post can have several tags, and one tag can have several posts in it).

Here are my prisma models:

```
model Post {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  slug String @unique
  title String
  body String
  tags Tag[]
}

model Tag {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  posts Post[]
  name String
  slug String @unique
}
```

And here's a mutation where I'm trying to create a post, and attach tags to it:

```
t.field('createPost', {
  type: 'Post',
  args: {
    title: nonNull(stringArg()),
    body: stringArg(),
    tags: list(arg({ type: 'TagInput' }))
  },
  resolve: async (_, args, context: Context) => {
    // Create tags if they don't exist
    const tags = await Promise.all(
      args.tags.map((tag) =>
        context.prisma.tag.upsert({
          create: omit(tag, "id"),
          update: tag,
          where: { id: tag.id || "" },
        })
      )
    )
    return context.prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        title: args.title,
        body: args.body,
        slug: `${slugify(args.title)}-${cuid()}`,
        // Trying to connect a post to an already existing tag
        // Without the "tags: {...} everything works
        tags: {
          set: [{id:"ckql6n0i40000of9yzi6d8bv5"}]
        },
        authorId: getUserId(context),
        published: true, // make it false once Edit post works.
      },
    })
  },
})
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

I'm getting an error:

```
Invalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation:
{
  data: {
    title: 'Post with tags',
    body: 'Post with tags body',
    slug: 'Post-with-tags-ckql7jy850003uz9y8xri51zf',
    tags: {
      connect: [
        {
          id: 'ckql6n0i40000of9yzi6d8bv5'
        }
      ]
    },
  }
}
Unknown arg `tags` in data.tags for type PostUncheckedCreateInput. Available args:
type PostUncheckedCreateInput {
  id?: String
  title: String
  body: String
  slug: String
}
```

It seems like the `tags` field on the post is missing? But I did run `prisma generate` and `prisma migrate`. Also I can successfully query tags on a post if I add them manually using Prisma Studio. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm running into the exact same issue right now and I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Never mind. I figured out my issue and it was unrelated to Prisma. Something is wrong with my build process and it wasn't updating the files in my build folder. Deleting my entire build folder and forcing a full rebuild fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issues with the following model:

```
model users {
  id       Int      @id @unique(map: "id") @default(autoincrement()) @db.Int
  email    String   @db.VarChar(100)
  alerts   alerts[]
}

model alerts {
  id       Int   @id @unique(map: "id") @default(autoincrement()) @db.Int
  user     users? @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id  Int?   @db.Int
  @@index([user_id])
}
```

Whenever I tried to create an `alerts` record with:

```
await prisma.alerts.create({
  data: {
    ...
    user_id: userId
  }
});
```

It was throwing:

```
Unknown arg `user_id` in data.user_id for type alertsCreateInput. Did you mean `user`? Available args:
type alertsCreateInput {
  ...
  user?: usersCreateNestedOneWithoutAlertsInput
}
```

But when I actually try to provide the user record with:

```
await prisma.alerts.create({
  data: {
    ...
    user: {
       connect: { id: userId }
    }
  }
});
```

It was throwing:

```
Unknown arg `user` in data.user for type alertsUncheckedCreateInput. Did you mean `user_id`? Available args:
type alertsUncheckedCreateInput {
  ...
  user_id?: Int | Null
}
```

So I was pulling my hair out. Complaining it needs `user` when I provide `user_id`, and when I actually provide that (`user`), it was requiring the `user_id`. I couldn't provide both of them because these 2 types of "type" where XOR-ed like this: `data: XOR<alertsCreateInput, alertsUncheckedCreateInput>`.

And I've finally made it work by making the user and user_id fields mandatory in the model definition.

From this:

```
  user     users? @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id  Int?   @db.Int
```

to this:

```
  user     users @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id  Int   @db.Int
```

Hope it might help future Googlers.

Comment: getting exact same error for user, user_id  and category , category_id.already have the fields as mandatory.its  a swing error .

Comment: user_id                 String?
  category_id             Int?
  user                    User?    @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [user_id])
  category                Category? @relation(fields: [category_id], references: [category_id])

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `connect` for the `author` as well. So the following will work fine:

```
return context.prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        title: args.title,
        body: args.body,
        slug: `${slugify(args.title)}-${cuid()}`,
        // Trying to connect a post to an already existing tag
        // Without the "tags: {...} everything works
        tags: {
          set: [{id:"ckql6n0i40000of9yzi6d8bv5"}]
        },
        author: { connect: { id: getUserId(context) } },
        published: true, // make it false once Edit post works.
      },
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue, I'm still getting the same error.
I do have the author and the published field, and I'm setting them just as you described, I've just removed them from my question to make it more concise and avoid confusing people with extra unrelated fields.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue arose when I created a new field on the prisma model called uid and tried to run the command `prisma migrate dev`

It brought the error

```
Error:
⚠️ We found changes that cannot be executed:

  • Step 0 Added the required column `uid` to the `Transactions` table without a default value. There are 1 rows in this table, it is not possible to execute this step.

You can use prisma migrate dev --create-only to create the migration file, and manually modify it to address the underlying issue(s).
Then run prisma migrate dev to apply it and verify it works.
```

I solved it by adding the `@default("")` to it.

```
model Transactions {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  uid String @default("")
  account String
  description String
  category String
  reference String
  currency String @default("GBP")
  amount String
  status String
  transactionDate String
  createdAt String
  updatedAt String
}
```